# I am trying to store user credentials ( name and email ) to cloud Firestore during the time user first signs up for the app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bth2a.png)

I am able to create new user but having trouble registering the credentials to Firestore.

Can someone pls tell me what am I doing wrong??

here's the code sample where I am registering user.

added necesary dependencies and code

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an image.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble registering users and storing their credentials in Firestore, you need to include the registration logic. Here's a general outline of how you can register a new user and store their information in Firestore using the Firebase services:

```
// Function to register a new user
Future<void> registerUser(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    // Create user with email and password
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    // Access the current user after registration
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    // Store user data in Firestore
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).set({
      'email': email,
      // Add additional user data as needed
    });

    print('User registered successfully!');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error registering user: $e');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you listen the event when `authStateChanges`?

Try to add this code to `onInit`

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
       print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
       print('User is signed in!');
    }
   });
```